# Android : How to use exoplayer 2.x.x to stream a radio link

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to stream for an online radio with exoplayer version rc2.x.x though an android service.

I have been trying to learn from all tutorials online I could but they are all prior to the 2.x.x version and a lot of them are video streaming related as well (which I don't need).

Does anyone has a very nice tutorial?

Comment: why do you want to use ExoPlayer at all?

Comment: Mediaplayer is really limited and I have been facing a lot of compatibility issue from one device to another. Even Google recommend nowadays to start using Exoplayer as far as I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have deep knowledge of ExoPlayer but I have  prepared this code snippet which can stream mp3 link.

EXO Player Verison : r2.0.4

```
  private void initMediaPlayer() {
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheCombatJackShow/~5/s_9fWPxLDu0/188058705-thecombatjackshow-the-j-cole-episode.mp3");
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                true);
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, Mp3Extractor.FACTORY,
                mHandler, null);

        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(mHandler);
        DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        //exoPlayer.addListener(this);

        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

This link may also help you :
https://medium.com/@emuneee/migrating-from-exoplayer-1-x-to-2-0-58fbda36b46c#.b8joifc36

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Nevertheless, when I try to keep a reference of the exoPlayer variable outside the method (i.e changing exoPlayer variable to a global one), it does not work anymore. Any idea?

Comment: are you getting exceptions?

Comment: No, I am not getting one. Nothing is just working when I declare the exoplayer variable as a global one in my Service class. in your case, since you declared your variable local, how will you stop your player by the way?